# Android create a Drag and drop with animation without overlapping

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-animation, android-cardview

I want a application which consist of drag and drop of cards with the animation such as,I need like this only pls help me out,
[image: on swipe left select based on the selection]

[image: on swipe right based on the selection]

Comment: This is the library that you're looking for: https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack

Comment: I have this but i need animation based on the drag and drop position!!how to do that??

Comment: [link](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*_4htbvWAFXq_67cbNqbiZA.gif)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is similar to the tinder app.You can use some github librarys like..

https://github.com/Grishu/TinderView-Control

https://github.com/lawloretienne/TinderStack?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4946

https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

Hope this helps you.

Comment: brother i am glad for ur answer,but i need specific, for a view which has a drag and drop to the another view he can select anyone out of 6 choice,

Comment: yeah where is drag and drop feature available in this library ? i also stuck with same problem.

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui you are saying... you want to drag a card and move to another activity...? Is this what you are saying.. I did not understand.

Comment: i need few fab buttons around the card with drag listener and when i place card on top of fab buttons a different action takes place depending on the user dragging

Comment: for better understandings pls open this link, [link](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1%2A_4htbvWAFXq_67cbNqbiZA.gif)

Comment: any luck on this mate ?